# How to turn off TFS alerts on Release

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a continuous integration build set up.  On check-in, it builds the solution, and then starts a release to DEV for each piece.  When those releases get done, I get an email for each separate release (every time someone checks in).  How do I turn those off?  Using TFS 2015.  I am the administrator and I don't want the emails to go out at all.

Comment: Are you using a personal alert or a team alert?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Per my comment on your answer, we are not using alerts at all.  Only 3 are set up in the entire system and those are the default ones that don't do anything for releases, only code review changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting is in the release definition environment. Follow the steps below to change the settings:

1. Click "Edit" button to edit the release definition.
2. Click "..." button on the environment and select "Deployment conditions" option.
3. Switch to "General" tab.
4. Set "Send emails notifications" to "Never".
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a personal alert, you just need to directly [delete the alert](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications#create-edit-or-delete-an-alert).

If your team are using a team alert, since you are a member of your team, you will also get one. Alerts are sent to each team member based on your preferred email address, which they set through your profile.

There is no setting for an alert which only sending to whole team just exclude you. If you really want this, you may have to ask your team admin  to remove you from the team.

There is a workaround to solve the problem. You can set some **rules in email tools** such as *Outlook*, once you got these kind of emials, delete them  immediately

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the issue.  There are only 3 alerts set up in the whole system, 1 personal alert for each of the 3 developers that is the default "A code review I am working on changes".  There are no team alerts configured.  This is why I can't find where this alert is coming from.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I want the alert turned off for everyone, not just myself.

Comment: Sorry the misunderstanding, eddie's screenshot is the related setting.